# How to access android context in a static method?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, static, package

My problem is this, I have a static method in which I need to call the method startActivity(). I tried creating another class from which I imported its context but that would not work since I still got the error;

> 'com.example.app5.menuActivity.this' cannot be referenced from a
> static context.

```
 public static void endDay() {
    Context context = getCXT.getAppContext();

    // EVENTS
    conf.day += 1;
    lblDay.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(conf.day)));
    //conf.dayRunning = false;
    //startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), ReportActivity.class));
    context.startActivity(new Intent(this, ReportActivity.class));

    gameLoop();
```

Im a beginner in Java and Android Studio so forgive me if my question seems out of the blue. However I would like to understand why the new intent "this" doesn't work and how I would do instead.

The second class, which I copied from [Static way to get 'Context' in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-in-android).

```
public class getCXT extends Application {

private static Context context;

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    MyApplication.context = getApplicationContext();
}

public static Context getAppContext() {
    return MyApplication.context;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> I have a static method in which I need to call the method startActivity()

Have the `static` method accept an `Activity` as a parameter, and call `startActivity()` on it.

> I would like to understand why the new intent "this" doesn't work and how I would do instead.

Quoting [Oracle's Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html):

> Within an instance method or a constructor, `this` is a reference to the current object — the object whose method or constructor is being called. You can refer to any member of the current object from within an instance method or a constructor by using `this`.

There is no `this` in a `static` method, however, which is one of the reasons why that code will not compile.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than

```
Context context = getCXT.getContext();
```

you can change this line to

```
Context context = getCXT.getAppContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes please try below

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(context, ReportActivity.class));
```

we can't use 'this' in static methods. It can used in non-static methods as they are object level methods. Static is like a class level, that is reason why we don't need object to access the static methods. We can call static methods with Class name directly.